# Array declared outside and inside loop gives different result in php mysql

Tags: php, arrays, json

Why will my array have different output within the while loop, like it fetch all data from database in json, but once I declare the array outside of the while loop as commented out it gives output single row in json? Am I missing something basic or what? Thanks in advance

```
$query = "SELECT * from creative ORDER BY rand()";

$rs = mysql_query($query);

//$arr = array();

while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)) {

    $arr[] = $obj;

    $cid = $arr -> id; //get id

} 

if (isset($imei) && !empty($imei)) {

$add = array('delay'=>"1800000"); //Add Objects to JSON Encoded Array

$arr[] = $add;

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried array push?

```
    $arr = array();
    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)) {

        //$arr[] = $obj;
        array_push($arr, $obj);
        //$cid = $arr -> id; //get id
    }
```

Comment: It's the same as **$arr[] = $obj;**, anyway **$arr->id;** won't work, so I think the pasted code is incorrect anyway :/

Comment: @islandmyth: if i defined array within while loop with array_push it fetches all rows and encoded them in json  ,but if i defined array outside while loop used as a variable $arr = $obj then i get only single row in json!

Comment: when you do this `$arr = $obj` inside loop you are assigning a new value to the array not appending. Previous value of the array will be overwritten. In this case the last value of `$obj` will be the value of your `$arr`

Comment: @islandmyth: but it doesn't assign whole database to $arr, only fetch one row. What should i do if i want only one row at a time in json and  append additional attribute to array?

Comment: @shihon `$arr[0]['delay']='1800000';`. You can also use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)` so that you will have a descriptive index.